# turning a list into a table with presence/absence in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following list:

```
gene1 file1
gene2 file2
gene3 file3
```

to turn into the following presence/absence table

```
       gene1    gene2    gene3
file1  +        -        -
file2  -        +        -
file3  -        -        +
```

is there some way in bash to do that?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, there is some way to do that in bash -- you could write a program to do it, same as you could in Python, C, etc.; however, writing your programs for you is not what we do here. If you *tried* to write it yourself, and asked about a problem you encountered in the process, that would get a much better response.

Comment: (If you don't know how to get started, "what bash data structure(s) can I use to store track/lookup presence of a specific pair in a set thereof?" is a perfectly good question; indeed, I'm liable to answer it).

Comment: (...should have made that, "writing your programs for you is not what *we're supposed to* do here, I suppose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there exists a character or string that can't exist in a genre name (below, I use `__` -- a double underscore), you can use an associative array to store and perform amortized O(1) lookups.

```
#!/bin/bash

input='gene1 file1
gene2 file2
gene3 file3'

declare -A known_files=( )
declare -A known_genres=( )
declare -A known_pairs=( )

while read -r genre file; do
  known_files[$file]=1
  known_genres[$genre]=1
  known_pairs[${genre}__${file}]=1
done <<<"$input"

# write header containing all known genres
printf '%s\t' '' "${!known_genres[@]}"; printf '\n'

# iterate through files, writing columns for each
for file in "${!known_files[@]}"; do
  printf '%s\t' "$file"
  for genre in "${!known_genres[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${known_pairs["${genre}__${file}"]} ]]; then
      printf '%s\t' "+"
    else
      printf '%s\t' "-"
    fi
  done
  printf '\n'
done
```

Note that this requires bash 4.0 or newer -- if you're on OS X (which ships an ancient release for licensing reasons), consider installing a modern release with MacPorts or Homebrew.